# SQLDependency Fails when SQL query compares Datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldependency

I'm working on a monitoring program for our shipping department that will show orders that are ready to ship.  I've been working with SQLDependency to do this and finally got it functioning, however, when I try to add some more specifics to my query, specifically comparing to a datetime column, the OnChange event is repeatedly triggered.  When I remove the comparison, it works perfectly.

I've been through [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I don't see anything saying this type of comparison isn't valid.

I've simplified my query down to:

```
SELECT [SALESLINE].[SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED]
FROM [dbo].[SALESLINE]
WHERE [SALESLINE].[SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED] >= '20130614'
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or another way to compare against a date?

I can post some of my code, but, as I said, it is working if I don't have a datetime in my WHERE clause.

Comment: >= new DateTime(2013,6,14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a typed parameter:

```
WHERE [SALESLINE].[SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED] > @someDateTime
```

and pass in a parameter of type DateTime.

Comment: After having some bizarre syntax error, I got this working and it worked like a charm.  Thanks a ton.  Do you know why this way works, but a static value doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the reason that the OnChange event was fired? It's likely that your query doesn't meet some of the [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx). If your query itself is to blame, it could be that the SQLDependency subscription itself is the cause of the repeated firing, in which case the reason should confirm this. You can check this in the handler by looking at the [eventargs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationeventargs).

Reading the rules, nothing obviously stands out. So perhaps try:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [SALESLINE].[SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED]
FROM [dbo].[SALESLINE]
WHERE [SALESLINE].[SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED] >= @d", conn)){
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d", myDate));
```

Comment: Yeah, I checked the SqlNotificationEventArgs and with the above query, it constantly shows a type of 'Subscribed'.  If I change my query and instead use a non-datetime column, it shows nothing until something changes in the DB,then the eventargs show 'Changed'.

Comment: That makes sense then. It must be a query issue. Have you tried using a command parameter as above?

Comment: Also, you've checked the type of the eventArgs - subscription meaning that it's failing to register - do the info and/or source of the eventargs give you anything to go on?

Comment: Paramaterizing the query seemed to have solved it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow! still a thing in 2019 (even in EF core SqlDependency).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your command parameter as follows. 
Make sure that dateVar is a DateTime type variable not a string.

cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateVar;

I hope this will help someone